# why can't urlEncoder.encode work like everyone else?

Tags: java, android, character-encoding, urlencode, url-encoding

I am having to do stupid s**t like this to get urlEncoding to work like other libraries (iOS, Javascript..) because [`java.net.URLEncoder`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/URLEncoder.html) is buggy or not written to standard encoding:

```
URLEncoder.encode(normalizeString(str), StandardCharsets.UTF_8.displayName())
                    .replace("+", "%20")
                    .replace("%40", "@")
                    .replace("*", "%2A");
```

`+` and `*` are not percent encoded while `@` is. and...now it's encoding forward slash `/`. wtf! is there a good explanation for this? Am I using the wrong Charset?

Comment: I suggest that you edit your question and provide a [mcve]. That would include literal input to `encode()` (i.e., not `normalizeString(str)`, which nobody knows what it returns), what that `encode()` call returns, and why you think that it is incorrect. IOW, post clear test cases that fail, and perhaps we can help identify the source of the failure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you misunderstood the role of the [`URLEncoder`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/URLEncoder.html). The [`UrlEncoder`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/URLEncoder.html) implements the [HTML Specifications](https://www.w3.org/TR/html4/interact/forms.html#h-17.13.4) for how to encode URLs in HTML forms.

In your case, I think, the library [`org.apache.commons.text`](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-text/) could be a better solution. It offer to you methods to escape characters like you want.

Comment: Thanks, I ended up using Google's Guava lib which is percent encoding as expected `UrlEscapers.urlFragmentEscaper().escape(string)`